Who is the god head of knowledge in Hinduism?
Hindu deities of knowledge and intelligence include Saraswati, Brahma , Hayagriva , Ganesha , Kartikeya , Matangi and Neela Saraswati(mahavidya Tara). So who among these is the most superior and has the accumulated power of all the mentioned deities?

Swachanda Tantra (Kashmir Shaiva Tantra)/ 11th Patala.:

Shri bhairava said - Sadyojata is Rigvedasvarupa, vama deva is Yajurveda Swarupa. Aghor is Samveda Swarupa, Tatpurusha is Atharvaveda Swarupa and Ishana is Sarvavidyatmaka i.e. Lord/Soul of All Knowledge.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Shiva Charanam Dasa Vishnu, just to clarify does Ishana the sum total of matangi, Saraswati , Ganesha etc knowledge gods? And how can one worship Ishana ?

Ishana represents Sun, Knowledge, Buddhi, Akasha (Soul), Pranava, The Ruler. You can worship T.A. mantra given in the other answer 1st verse or just utter Pranava (️). It is the Turiyateeta form means all worships to any bhagwan ultimately goes to him only. Prd..

Please will you specify the T.A mantra. Thank you.

"Ishana Sarva Vidyanam Ishvara Sarva Bhuthanam Bhramhadipathir Bhramhanodhipathir Bhramha Shivome Asthu Sadashiva Om!!" Meaning : Ishana is present in the form of all the Vidyas or knowledge & Ishvara is present in all the things of this Universe & he is the head of Bhramha "

Ishana is Ishwara only. Plus, you can also utter OM. And You are welcome. ..

Here is the Sadyojadham archetype mentioned in Krishna YajurVeda:

Sadyojatham : "Ishana Sarva Vidyanam Ishvara Sarva Bhuthanam
Bhramhadipathir Bhramhanodhipathir Bhramha Shivome Asthu Sadashiva
Om!!" Meaning : Ishana is present in the form of all the Vidyas or
knowledge & Ishvara is present in all the things of this Universe & he
is the head of Bhramha "

Next Kaivalya Upaniṣhad comes into the picture:

तस्मै स होवाच पितामहश्च श्रद्धाभक्तिध्यानयोगादवैहि || 2 विविक्तदेशे च
सुखासनस्थः शुचिः समग्रीवशिरःशरीरः । अन्त्याश्रमस्थः सकलेन्द्रियाणि
निरुध्य भक्त्या स्वगुरुं प्रणम्य || 4 हृत्पुण्डरीकं विरजं विशुद्धं
विचिन्त्य मध्ये विशदं विशोकम् ।अचिन्त्यमव्यक्तमनन्तरूपं शिवं
प्रशान्तममृतं ब्रह्मयोनिम् ॥ 5 तमादिमध्यान्तविहीनमेकं विभुं
चिदानन्दमरूपमद्भुतम् । तथादि उमासहायं परमेश्वरं प्रभुं त्रिलोचनं
नीलकण्ठं प्रशान्तम् । ध्यात्वा मुनिर्गच्छति भूतयोनिं समस्तसाक्षिं तमसः
परस्तात् ॥ 6 स एव सर्वं यद्भूतं यच्च भव्यं सनातनम् ।ज्ञात्वा तं
मृत्युमत्येति नान्यः पन्था विमुक्तये ॥ 9 (Rishi Ashvalayana asked The
Grandsire (grandfather/पितामहश्च) Lord Brahma for the highest hidden
knowledge called the Brahma-Vidya, which is only embraced by learned
sages).
(पितामहश्च वाच) Lord Brahma said: focus and confidence in the teaching
of Guru/Scriptures (Shraddha श्रद्धा), surrendering oneself in
devotion without ego/aham (Bhakti भक्ति), meditative contemplation
(Dhyana ध्यान) of Yoga to achieve the union of oneself with reality
(Yoga योगा), are the means to strive (वेह).
Lord Brahma continued: Seated comfortably in yogic posture (सुख आसन),
keeping the spine, neck and head in one line (शुचिः समग्रीवशिरःशरीरः
), in a consecrated/pure/undisturbed location (विविक्त देश), with the
mind like a sage (अन्त्याश्रमस्थ) – retrieving all senses
inwards/turned-off (सकलेन्द्रियाणि निरुध्य) – bow down in respect to
one’s guru (भक्त्या स्वगुरुं प्रणम्य). With a pure (विशुद्धं) heart
centered (विरजं) like the lotus flower (हृत्पुण्डरीकं), without
despair/grief or anxiety (विशदं विशोकम्), with centered focus of
thoughts (विचिन्त्य –मध्ये) on that which is the unthinkable
(अचिन्त्यम), the unmanifest (अव्यक्तम), the infinite timeless form
(अनन्त-रूपं), which is ever-auspicious (शिवं), ever-blissful and
immortal (प्रशान्तम अमृतं), which is the abode/womb of creation
(ब्रह्म -योनि), the one that is without (विहीन) beginning or middle or
end (तम अदि-मध्य-अन्त), the one singularity (ऐकं), the one
almighty/all-pervading (विभुं), the one who is the personification of
eternal bliss of Cit (चिदानन्दम -रूपम), who is astonishing/mystical
(अद्भुतम्), the consort of the ever-auspicious Uma (उमा सहायं ), who
is the eternal self-governing ruler (परमेश्वरं प्रभुं) with three eyes
(त्रिलोचनं) and a blue neck (नीलकण्ठं), who is forever peaceful in His
own self (प्रशान्तम्), mediate your thoughts on this form (ध्यात्वा).
A true sage (मुनिर्गच्छति) will reach/realize the source and womb of
all beings (भूत-योनिं) and the only witness to all (समस्त-साक्षिं) and
beyond all unmanifest (तमसः परस्तात्). He alone is the entirety and
what is now and what was before (एव सर्वं यद्भूतं), He alone is great
(भव्यं), He alone is eternal (सनातनम्). Knowing/realizing Him
(ज्ञात्वा तं) overcomes death (मृत्यु-मत्येति) and there is no
(नान्यः) approach other than this (पन्था विमुक्तये ). Kaivalya
Upaniṣhad 2

Source: Link
Source: Link
